# How to include shared context to every spec in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a shared context:

```
shared_context :current_country do
  let!(:country) { create :country, slug: "kw" } unless Country.find_by(slug: "kw").present?
end
```

I need to have access to the `country` variable in each spec.

To use it, I need to ***`include_context :current_country`*** in every spec file. Is it possible to avoid having this line in each spec file and instead configure the context to be available everywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare your shared context

```
RSpec.shared_context "shared stuff" do
  let!(:country) do
    create :country, slug: "kw"
  end unless Country.find_by(slug: "kw").present?
end
```

And include it in config

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include_context "shared stuff"
end
```

Comment: Though this might answer the question, please also provide a short explanation what your code does and why it solves the initial problem.